# Load Android image in React Native

Tags: android, image, react-native

I'm trying to load image from Android's drawble resources library using React Native.

I tried to require it like this:

```
<Image source={require("image!some-image")} />
```

And:

```
<Image source={{uri: "some-image", isStatic: true}} />
```

But no luck.. I know that I can require image from the js path but in this case I need it from the 'res' folder.

Comment: Is that image in a drawable folder that is valid for the dpi of the device you are testing on ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Android local image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885564/react-native-android-local-image)

Answer (score 1):

There are three things that could possibly be wrong.

1. Android does not support '-' in image names. use '_' instead.
2. Ensure that you are rebuilding the app when you add the asset (`react-native run-android`). This should be done every time you add/modify an asset to the res folder

3.There ought to be a ',' before isStatic.

`<Image source={{uri: "some-image" isStatic: true}} />`. I'm guessing this was a typo